# google map api key for Java project

Tags: java, google-maps, netbeans-7

which google map key will be applicable for following code and how can we generate it...i tried to generate it from "http://www.code.google/apis/maps" but there was number of keys available but I don't know what type of key will be usefull for this code and process for generating it..

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Google Map Demo App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>   
    <%@ page import="org.netbeans.saas.*, org.netbeans.saas.google.*" %>

    <%

        try {
            String address = "16 Network Circle, Menlo Park";
            java.lang.Integer zoom = 15;
            String iframe = "false";

            RestResponse result = GoogleMapService.getGoogleMap
            (address, zoom, iframe);
            //TODO - Uncomment the print Statement below to print result.
      //out.println("The SaasService returned: "+result.getDataAsString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

       %>


      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are 4 kinds of keys you can set up for your API. They are Server, Browser, iOS, Android.

if your user is using your app in a web browser, then you should use the Browser key.